# Handling .Net UTF-8 strings in Erlang

Tags: .net, utf-8, string, erlang

I'm playing a bit with erlang and the distributed db Mnesia.

One of the first problem I'm facing is the incompatibilty beetween the 'int list' strings of erlang and .Net UTF-8 strings.

Is there any good conversion library?

Thanks

Comment: .NET strings are inherently UTF-16 in memory, not UTF-8. UTF-8 is the default encoding used by most APIs if you omit an encoding, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new [R13B](http://erlang.org/download.html) release of Erlang has better support for unicode.

The new Unicode module is documented [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) and the Unicode support implemented is described in the EEP 10 ([Erlang Enhancement Proposal 10](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0010.html)).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen, erlang uses UTF32, so using [System.Text.Encoding.UTF32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf32.aspx) might do the trick to get the ints for the list, then you need to create the list from those. Not tested though.

The following snippet may help (it creates an array of unicode `int`s which should match the ones expected for the erlang list):

```
public static int[] GetIntsForString(string source) {
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(source);
    int[] result = new int[source.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) {
        result[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, i*4);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Does the one added in the edit help, or is there something else you need help with?